# Представляти у значенні презентувати

Tags: вживання-слів

В комерційних і новинних текстах часто можна натрапити на речення типу "Motorola представила свої бюджетні смартфони". За Тлумачним словником української мови в 11т.  дієслово *представляти* має такі значення:

> **ПРЕДСТАВЛЯТИ**, яю, яєш, недок., ПРЕДСТАВИТИ, влю, виш; мн. представлять; док., перех., книжн.
>
> 1. кого кому, також із сл. одне одному, одного одному. Знайомлячи з кимось, називати чи характеризувати кого-небудь; рекомендувати.
> 2. тільки недок. Бути представником кого-, чого-небудь, заступати кого-небудь, діючи за його дорученням, від його імені, захищаючи чиїсь
>      інтереси, здійснюючи чиюсь волю; репрезентувати.
>
> //  Бути виразником, еквівалентом чогось.
>
> //  із сл. інтереси. Діяти за дорученням когось, здійснювати чиюсь
>   волю.
>
> 3. Показувати, зображувати кого-, що-небудь у творах літератури, мистецтва, у розповіді, усній або писемній характеристиці.
> 4. до чого, на що. Порушувати питання про нагороду чи підвищення по службі, на посаді.

Перше значення ніби-то підходить, але має зауваження, що така дія може відбуватися між істотами. То чи доречне вживання слова представляти у значенні презентувати, рекомендувати стосовно товарів чи послуг?

Answer (score 1):

Знайшла таку [інформацію](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/5.php):

> “У яких випадках уживають іменник презентація, а в яких — репрезентація?”
>
> Цими лексемами нерідко послуговуються наші ЗМІ, на них можна натрапити в різних текстах, та й у розмові чуємо презентація нової збірки лірики чи томика прози, презентація виставки, гімназії, клубу і навіть конференції. Ще не так давно в одинадцятитомному Словникові української мови модне іншомовне слово тлумачилося тільки як фінансовий термін “пред’явлення грошового документа до виплати”, а презентант — як його пред’явник. Обидва іменники споріднені з латинським praesento — “передаю, вручаю”, звідси й відоме презент — “подарунок”. Згодом слово презентація розширило сполучуваність з іменниковими назвами, позначаючи разом святкову подію, урочисте відкриття, **представлення чогось**. Через презентацію широко інформують про певне явище, факт. Найчастіша сполучуваність: відбулася (відбудеться) презентація. Отож презентація не має зв’язку з презентувати — “дарувати”, “підносити подарунки”. Але виявляє його з **репрезентувати — “представляти**”, з репрезентація — “представництво”. Вони споріднені з латинським representatio — “наочне зображення”.
>
> Очевидно, під впливом поширених тепер презентацій плутають дієслова і замість репрезентувати (представляти) ставлять іноді презентувати: “Творчість художника презентувала тогочасне образотворче мистецтво” (з газети). Правильно: газета репрезентує інтереси дебютантів, гідно репрезентувати свою країну. Частіше це дієслово потребує після себе знахідного відмінка (кого, що), але подібно до представляти (кого-що, кому-чому) вживається також із давальним.

Схожу інформацію знаходимо [тут](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine53-54-26.pdf):

> ...Тим часом презентація набуло значення «урочисте представлення», «свято»,
>   «відкриття» і розширило свою сполучуваність з іменниковими назвами, позначаючи разом
>   святкову подію, урочисте відкриття, **представлення чого-небудь**, напр., виставки, видання,
>   книжки, збірки письменника, гімназії, клубу, вищої школи підприємців...

І ще кілька джерел: [1](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/110449/36-Horodenska.pdf?sequence=1), [2](http://vilne.org.ua/2016/02/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/).
Беручи до уваги, все вище сказане, я думаю, що *представляти* у контексті "Motorola представила свої бюджетні смартфони" цілком доцільне.