# Значення слова "презентувати"

Tags: значення-слів, вибір-слова

Шукаючи відповідь на питання [Представляти у значення презентувати](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) наткнулась на розбіжність у значенні слова *презентувати*. В [уроках державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/5.php) зазначено:

> презентація не має зв’язку з презентувати — “дарувати”, “підносити подарунки”. Але виявляє його з репрезентувати — “представляти”, з репрезентація — “представництво”. Вони споріднені з латинським representatio — “наочне зображення”.
>
> Очевидно, під впливом поширених тепер презентацій плутають дієслова і замість репрезентувати (представляти) ставлять іноді презентувати: “Творчість художника презентувала тогочасне образотворче мистецтво” (з газети). Правильно: газета репрезентує інтереси дебютантів, гідно репрезентувати свою країну. Частіше це дієслово потребує після себе знахідного відмінка (кого, що), але подібно до представляти (кого-що, кому-чому) вживається також із давальним.

Також  у ["Культура мови на щодень"](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine53-54-26.pdf) знаходимо аналогічне твердження.

І СУМ подає одне значення слова:

> ПРЕЗЕНТУВА́ТИ, ую, уєш, недок. і док., перех., заст., розм. Передавати що-небудь у власність як подарунок; дарувати. Згадалася [Наливайкові] її довга розповідь про чоловіка Яна.. та про тисячі золотих червінців, що їх презентував удові король Баторій за ті чоловікові заслуги (Іван Ле, Наливайко, 1957, 68); Королева з своїм королем, щасливі, плазували біля ніг Наполеона, щоб він лише ласкаво на них глянув і щось презентував з пограбованого в Росії та інших країнах (Панас Кочура, Золота грамота, 1960, 30).

Натомість в цьому [джерелі](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/110449/36-Horodenska.pdf?sequence=1) сказано:

> Презентувати, презентація, презентований означають ‘публічно представля-
>   ти щось нове, ознайомлювати з якимсь новим вагомим здобутком’

І [тут](http://liknep.pp.ua/viewtopic.php?p=1034):

> Презентувати:
>      - публічно представляти що-небудь нове, що недавно з’явилося, було створено: "На зустрічі Оксана Забужко презентувала свою нову книгу"
>      - передавати що-небудь у власність як подарунок; дарувати: "Хочу Вам презентувати цей скромний Роллс-Ройс".

Також на багатьох інтернет-ресурсах використовують презентувати в контексті ["Nokia презентувала власний планшет"](http://ipress.ua/news/nokia_prezentuvala_vlasnyy_planshet_i_novi_telefony_seriy_lumia_ta_asha_31253.html).

То в якому контекті можливе вживання слова *презентувати*?

Answer (score 1):

Перш за все знайдемо це слово в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/prezentuvaty), де у нього є лише одне значення:

> **ПРЕЗЕНТУВА́ТИ**, ую, уєш, недок. і док., перех., заст., розм. Передавати
>   що-небудь у власність як подарунок; дарувати.

Дивимось на [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53408/25605.html) :

> Очевидно, під впливом поширених тепер презентацій плутають дієслова і
>   замість репрезентувати (представляти) ставлять іноді презентувати:
>   “Творчість художника презентувала тогочасне образотворче мистецтво” (з
>   газети). Правильно: газета репрезентує інтереси дебютантів, гідно
>   репрезентувати свою країну.

Як бачимо у нашій мові і справді часто неправильно вживають слово "презентувати", однак варто розрізняти слова презентувати і репрезентувати. Також, якщо заглянемо в [орфографічний словник](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=269936), то побачимо, що "презентувати" якщо й вживається в значенні "представляти щось", то рідко.

Comment: Зазначу, що СУМ совітський, тобто сучасне слово анґліцізм (як тут вже згадано) [презентація](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Презентація_(виступ)) не записане через небуття (чи непопулярність) його тодї. Між иншим, воно теж _передає_ щось, а саме _відомости_. Але загалом згоден.